# How to have 2 domains with same codebase with Django?

Tags: django

There should be two sites with the following domain and any port:

```
domain.name1

domain.name2
```

Both of these sites should point to the single codebase.
I want to create a common feature that will print "Hello World!" on the browser.

```
domain.name1 should print "Hello World!" with a "Red" color.

domain.name2 should print "Hello World!" with a "Green" color.
```

I have no idea where to start exactly. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at Sites Framework, it will help you do this -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/sites/